# Fonts displaying strangely on certain pages using Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I never noticed before, but in certain pages, Google Chrome seems to be rendering fonts faultily. I notice it most on the Google Maps engine, but it even does this inside its own settings pages. Here are some screenshots about it:
[image: Google Maps]
[image: Codecademy]

I've already tried editing the `chrome://flags/` setting "`GPU compositing on all pages`", but that had no effect.

I'm running Chrome version Version 30.0.1599.69m

Comment: mac osx or windows?

Comment: This is a common complaint (in my circles anyway) with Chrome's rendering engine. I don't know if there's a way to fix it.

Comment: @Chris I'm having this problem on Windows; I am **not** having the same problem on Ubuntu running version 30.0.1599.66 beta.

Comment: @RandolphWest Is the rendering engine the same across the platform? Because I don't see those problems in Ubuntu, just Windows.